# Creation of unexpected tuple value

Tags: python-2.7, set, tuples, addition

I am dealing with somewhat of a mystery and hoped for some clarity. I wrote a script for finding dice roll combinations adding to 24 that looks like the following:

```
start=[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
outcomes=set(tuple(start)) #Use a set to ensure uniqueness

index_list=np.random.randint(0,8,1000)

#This little snippet adds one and subtracts one randomly, keeping total at 24
for i in xrange(0,500):
    upper=index_list[i]
    downer=index_list[i+20]

    if start[upper]!=6 and start[downer]!=1:
        start[upper]=start[upper]+1
        start[downer]=start[downer]-1
        outcomes.add(tuple(start))

print outcomes
```

What I am running into, is that When I look at outcomes, there is a single 3 of type 'int' in there.

```
set([(4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3), 3, (2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3), (4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3),(4, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3)])
```

While I could certainly remove it, I am just curious how it is getting in there to begin with? My initial guess was the index list might be producing an index outside of [0-7], but it is not. I've looked for a similar question other places, but have yet to find a similar issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` expects an iterable. You're passing a `tuple` which is an iterable.
`set` iterates through it, leaving just 1 value: 3 (because your tuple only contains the same 3 value).

You have to put your element in a list or tuple so it is seen as a single element (exactly the same problem when you pass a string and it is unexpectedly iterated upon)

The rest of your code is OK and has nothing to do with the problem.

Do this instead:

```
outcomes=set([tuple(start),])
```

now `set` iterates through a list of 1 tuple, effectively creating `tuple` elements.

You could do that also, maybe simpler:

```
outcomes=set()
outcomes.add(tuple(start))
```

there's no ambiguity since you're adding 1 element. It's not iterated through.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Whoever downvoted this why did you do so? Is this not a pythonic way of doing this, or is there some other reason to downvote it?

Comment: I was about to comment on the downvote. Someone who misread the question... I'm not getting it either.

Comment: @MasonGardner I did not downvote, but the reason I did not upvote is that the explanation is a little misleading/unlcear in my opinion. `set` does expect an iterable, but [tuples *are* iterables](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) - this answer makes it sound like they are not. The reason you are getting `3` is because that is the only unique value in `(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)`.

Comment: @elethan I have edited my post, I thought it was easy to understand (the OP got it at once).